# Shapefile saving to unknown format instead of geojson

Tags: qgis, shapefile, geojson

I have a shapefile and would like to export a single record (polygon), which I've selected, to GeoJSON.

I have never had a problem with this before.  I've checked the CRS - it is defined as ESPG: 4326.  I choose Save As... > Tick "only selected features" but then I am given an unknown table instead of a GeoJSON file.

Why might this be happening?

Here is a link to the shapefile in question: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxKUeZA_oaslWkNPT3Q1UldKZzg)

[image]

Comment: "Unknown" table can be produced if you choose 'No geometry' at the **Geometry | Geometry type** section of the *Save vector layer as...* dialog.

Comment: I've tried `Automatic` and `Polygon`. Still the same result

Comment: Have you chosen a different filename, format `Geojson`, in a folder where you have write access?

Comment: yes that also..

Comment: Perhaps you have also multipolygons in the selection.

Comment: GeoJSON is the only format you are having trouble in saving? If you can save the selected polygon as a shapefile there may be ways to troubleshoot.

Comment: have you tried saving another polygon from that shapefile as a geojson? Or try to export that shapefile again and then try to export the polygon again.

Comment: Yes, I am able to save the selected polygon as a shapefile, but not as a GeoJSON.   Also, one other thing that I've noticed is that when I click "Save As.." and choose ESRI Shapefile, the Encoding can be changed.  When  I choose GeoJSON, the Encoding cannot be changed.  Not sure if that indicates something.

Comment: Also, I've uploaded the shapefile and linked it in the question above

Comment: I could reproduce the "Unknown table" with the provided Shapefile, thank you. After running **Vector | Geometry Tools | Multipart to Singleparts**, the new layer (of two singleparts) could be saved as proper GeoJASON. (Hats off to @user30184 !) the_darkside Would you try it at your end, too?

Comment: @the_darkside I'm glad it worked out :) BTW today I ran **Vector | Geometry Tools | Check geometry** tool on the downloaded (original) shapefile. It also rectified the error. Confused, I stopped trying to find the root cause of this problem (sorry)... Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le me summarize our findings and unknowns ("as is" basis).

[What we found]

- Format conversion of a Vector layer to GeoJSON through "Save As..." function creates a Table layer without geometries, with a distinctive suffix **Unknown** when it appears on Layers Panel.
- This happens when the GeoJSON could not take geometry information from its original layer, for instance:

  - User choose not to save its geometry, by selecting 'No geometry' at the Geometry | Geometry type section, or
  - The original layer (or selected feature) had geometry error(s).

[Unknown]

- Root cause and where was the error.
- Some vector operations which access its geometry had rectified the error, but the reason why they had been successful was not clear.

Happy to update and edit further.